# make one table look like two tables

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is controlled by a style sheet.
the table has been created from a poster which my boss wants it to look like. the problem i am having is on the poster there is a gap between two of the columns.

I have tried just putting two tables side by side however this caused me issues if viewed on a mobile devise, so i tried to add a column that had a border left and right and the same colour background as the rest of the page but i cant get rid of the top/bottom borders that are in place from the style sheet.

Style sheet.

```
.table__container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  border-bottom: 0px dashed #DDD;
}
table tr th {
  color: #88B53D;
}
table tr th, table tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.row__header {
  border-top: 3px solid #DDD;
}
.row__header--day {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

CSS on page

```
.nothing {
        border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
```

HTML table

```
<div class="table__container">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <td class="nothing">Gap should be here</td>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row__header" style="text-align:center;">
                        <th class="row__header--day"></th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="nothing">Gap should be here</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

The style sheet was provided to me as part of our branding so i cant mess with it too much.

Comment: If it's not tabular data you shouldn't use tables. There are many alternatives. Or _**must**_ you use tables?

Comment: "I have tried just putting two tables side by side however this caused me issues if viewed on a mobile devise" - This is the problem that will be easier to tackle than what you're trying to accomplish here. Do some reading on responsive design and media queries.

Comment: Sorry @jaunt and i should of pointed out that are about 10 rows to the table not just the two in my question but just thought adding all the rows would not be necessary

Comment: @JonUleis Yes usually i would rather use divs and media queries but this put the information in the wrong places and could not think of a better way to display that many rows.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the expected result? If yes then I will add some explanation.

```css
.table__container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

table tr td.gap{
  width:40%;
  text-align:center;
  border:none;
}

table tr td{
  border:1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div class="table__container">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td class="gap"></td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td class="gap"></td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is the effect I am looking for. can you just do border-top:none; ? as column 3 and 4 will have no side borders so need to add them to the gap.